# Where are network drive credentials saved in the latest Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, network-drive, credentials-manager

Until recently (before year 2022) network drive credentials were saved in Credentials Manager/Windows Credentials. Now there are no entries there. It looks like they were moved somewhere. Where there are now?

Comment: Are you sure they are saved? Are username and password perhaps the same instead?

Comment: Server credentials are saved to Credential Manager on my machine, but not network mapping for network drives. The entries were not moved - they were not there.

Comment: Yes, where are they? Same with Windows 11, I connected to a NAS, but just can't change the account anymore.

Comment: @viuser - There shouldn't be any difference this part of Windows has not been updated in over a decade.

Comment: @Ramhound the fact is that the NAS (or network drive) credentials are not in the Credential Manager. I see RDP, mail and Microsoft accounts there, but not NAS. So WHERE are they? Or: how can we reset them without restarting?

Comment: @viuser - You are talking about the credentials that are required, while in `File Explorer - File -> Map network` drive? Did you use `/savecred` when you ran the `net use` command?

Comment: @Ramhound I just opened the share provided by a NAS. The password-dialogue appeared, and I entered my credentials there. I'm authorized now but the credentials don't appear in the Credential Manager...

Answer (score 1):

I just mapped a network drive in Windows 11 22H2 while choosing to save credentials, and Windows credentials for network shares and mapped drives are still being stored in Credential Manager.

If you have entered credentials to access a network share or to map a network drive without choosing to save those credentials then they are being cached in your login session. Once you log out and log back in you should be asked for credentials again if you try to access the share or a mapped drive.

On a side note, Windows will always attempt to:

- Use your current login credentials first when accessing a network share, then prompt for credentials if that fails.
- Use your current login credentials when accessing a mapped drive unless Connect using different credentials is checked.

Therefore, if your user exists on the remote PC, or if both PCs are part of the same domain and your domain user has access rights, you will be signed in automatically using your login credentials which won't need to be saved.

Note that this answer doesn't cover any changes to this behavior that might arise from using Microsoft Account and sync.

**EDIT:**

Kerberos credentials are cached in Windows registry under `HKLM\Security\Cache`. In order to see those keys you need to open registry editor by impersonating either `NT AUTHORITY\System` or `NT AUTHORITY\Trusted Installer` user.

[image: Kerberos Credential Cache in Registry Editor]

Since you haven't specified whether you are using a domain user or a local user which has a same username and password on the remote machine or what are your network sharing security settings and/or policies it isn't possible to give a more specific answer to your question.

Comment: Still missing. I suspect it has something to do that Windows uses Kerberos authentications sometimes?

Comment: if the computer is not shared, I map drives with a batch script - net use * /delete /y and Net use x: \\server\share /user:admin passwordforadmin - if the share is not removed before reconnecting it just don't connect.

Comment: `net use * /delete /y` does **not** delete my credentials for this! I can still connect without being prompted for a password. Despite the NAS username being different from my Windows login name.

Comment: Finally, I found it: `klist purge` resets the credentials and I have to enter them again when I access the network share. But the question, where the credentials are saved is still open...

Comment: @viuser I have updated the answer with clarification on Kerberos caching. If that still doesn't answer your question you will have to provide more information about your environment.

Comment: @IgorLevicki `domain user or a local user which has a same username and password on the remote machine` => I'm logged in with a local user account and use a different username / password on the remote machine.

Comment: ok, I found the credentials by using PowerRun

Comment: @viuser You still didn't tell us if the other machine is in the same domain or not. Never mind, you could at least say where you found them and accept an answer if it is good enough.